# Between Operator not functioning as expect on Time Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, between

I would like to extract the time portion from `rfq_create_date_time` and select only records between two times. The time is in GMT but I'm only interested in records from Hong Kong timezone i.e. 23.00 GMT to 10.00 GMT.

```
created_date_time       rfq_create_date_time    rfq_create_time
2018-06-28 21:04:28.637 2018-06-28 00:04:52.000 00:04:52.0000000
2018-06-21 00:08:09.110 2018-06-21 00:08:03.000 00:08:03.0000000
2018-06-05 00:18:28.853 2018-06-05 00:18:27.000 00:18:27.0000000
2018-06-05 00:31:51.110 2018-06-05 00:29:21.000 00:29:21.0000000
2018-06-27 21:04:39.713 2018-06-27 00:36:29.000 00:36:29.0000000
2018-06-22 00:37:39.650 2018-06-22 00:37:08.000 00:37:08.0000000
2018-06-22 21:04:21.427 2018-06-22 00:39:01.000 00:39:01.0000000
2018-06-01 00:42:59.297 2018-06-01 00:40:29.000 00:40:29.0000000
2018-06-22 21:04:21.427 2018-06-22 00:40:56.000 00:40:56.0000000
2018-06-19 21:04:24.093 2018-06-19 00:41:26.000 00:41:26.0000000
2018-06-21 21:04:30.197 2018-06-21 00:42:04.000 00:42:04.0000000
2018-06-14 00:43:28.013 2018-06-14 00:43:25.000 00:43:25.0000000
2018-06-01 00:46:13.280 2018-06-01 00:43:43.000 00:43:43.0000000
```

The time field has been created successfully (`rfq_create_time`):

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
(
    select      
                R.created_date_time,
                R.rfq_create_date_time,
                cast(R.rfq_create_date_time as time) as rfq_create_time,
    from        [ecomm_rfq].[dbo].[RFQ]                 R   WITH (NOLOCK) 
                join [ecomm_rfq].[dbo].[RFQ_RFQLEG]     L   WITH (NOLOCK)   
                on R.unique_id = L.unique_id                --inner join
    where
                R.rfq_create_date_time >= '2018-06-01'
                and R.rfq_create_date_time <= '2018-06-30'          
)       as innerTable

WHERE rfq_create_time between ('23:00:00.0000000' and '10:00:00.0000000')
order by rfq_create_time
```

The between operator is throwing the following error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.
```

is there a way to select rows based on a Time field which span midnight?

Comment: remove the brackets from around the 'and' values

Comment: Syntax corrected. No records are being returned. When I change the 23 to 00 many records from 00:00:00.0000000 to 10:00:00.0000000. So issue is capturing all rows which happened between 11pm GMT and 12.00 am GMT

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output to the question.

Comment: Sample data added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
(
    select      
                R.created_date_time,
                R.rfq_create_date_time,
                cast(R.rfq_create_date_time as time) as rfq_create_time,
    from        [ecomm_rfq].[dbo].[RFQ]                 R   WITH (NOLOCK) 
                join [ecomm_rfq].[dbo].[RFQ_RFQLEG]     L   WITH (NOLOCK)   
                on R.unique_id = L.unique_id                --inner join
    where
                R.rfq_create_date_time >= '2018-06-01'
                and R.rfq_create_date_time <= '2018-06-30'          
)       as innerTable

WHERE rfq_create_time not between '10:00:00.0000000' and '23:00:00.0000000'
order by rfq_create_time
```

Comment: Makes sense ; ) Curious as to why my the >23 failed though?

Comment: @PeterLucas what your query does is it asks for a time greater than 23 but less than 10 which as you can understand won't give you any time.

Answer (score 2):

Braces should be included only if u want to make this computation in prior to additional arithmetic operations but not prefered for datetime operations
Hence

this is wrong     `rfq_create_time between ('23:00:00.0000000' and '10:00:00.0000000')`

This is correct `rfq_create_time between '23:00:00.0000000' and '10:00:00.0000000'`